# Entity Framework bound textbox text not displaying changes to entity

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, binding

I am learning Entity Framework with version 6 and VS 2013 update 5. As an exercise I made a simple Contacts form using Northwind's Employees for people data and changed the entity generating code to use an observable collection for Employee. The form (simplified here) has a DataGrid showing the people and text boxes for first name and last name. They all have the same CollectionViewSource for a DataContext. There is also a button that will revert changes by reloading the table. This works fine except when I revert the changes - if I change a name in a textbox and revert changes without selecting a new line in the DataGrid the changed name still shows in the textbox. The DataGrid shows changes immediately, the textboxes show changes when I select a new line, it's just this one thing. How do I make the textbox show the new data in the DataContext without adding unnecessary dependencies to the form?
I did check that using INotifyPropertyChanged resolved the problem, but I would prefer not to have to use another kludge, like PropertyChanged.Fody, after altering the .tt file.

This is the generated Employee

```
namespace EF_one_table
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

    public partial class Employee
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Employee()
        {
            this.Employees1 = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
        }

        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        ... the rest of the table's fields ....

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees1 { get; set; }
        public virtual Employee Employee1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The XAML

```
<Window x:Class="EF_one_table.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EF_one_table"
        Title="COPY 3" Height="299.179" Width="530.836" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="peopleViewSource" Source="local:Employee" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource peopleViewSource}" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <DataGrid Name="dg1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="215" Width="226" 
                 AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="200">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" Width="Auto" />
                                <TextBlock Text=" "/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LastName}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <TextBlock Margin="265,36,0,0" Text="First Name" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBlock Margin="265,75,0,0" Text="Last Name" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBox Height="23" Margin="351,36,0,0" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" />
        <TextBox Height="23" Margin="351,75,0,0" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Text="{Binding Path=LastName}" />
        <Button x:Name="btnDiscard" Content="Discard All Changes" Margin="391,126,0,0"  Width="110" Click="btnDiscard_Click" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the C#

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private NorthwindEntities _context = new NorthwindEntities();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CollectionViewSource peopleViewSource = this.Resources["peopleViewSource"] as CollectionViewSource;
            _context.Employees.Load();
            peopleViewSource.Source = _context.Employees.Local;
        }

        private void btnDiscard_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Discard All Changes","Lose your work!",MessageBoxButton.YesNo,MessageBoxImage.Question,MessageBoxResult.No) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                // expose the ObjectContext inside the DbContext instance for the Refresh() method
                var objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_context).ObjectContext;
                // "Property changes made to objects in the object context will be replaced with values from the data source. 
                objContext.Refresh(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, _context.Employees);
                dg1.Items.Refresh();
             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should have a look at the MVVM pattern and you should not bind data classes to your UI. For updating the UI you have to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in the class you bound to your UI and you don't want to have this in your data class.

Comment: Did you try to refresh the CollectionViewSource? peopleViewSource.View.Refresh() or peopleViewSource.View.CurrentPosition = 0.

Comment: mm8, once again you come to my rescue. peopleViewSource.View.Refresh() is what is needed. It takes the place of dg1.Items.Refresh() and does the additional work.